# First decimal digit of a very large number.

Tags: perfect-powers

Find the first digit (the left one) of the number $2016^{2016}$, not by actually compute it. I know the solution is 7, thanks to Wolfram Alpha's power, but I did not succeeded in finding it.

Question number two: how may i calculate log values used in solving this?

Comment: Pardon for the question. I didn't find it. Thanks

Comment: Its ok. You can edit your question with some new doubts. Like how to calculate log values used in solving this.

Comment: And give reference to that question too.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1136486/finding-the-first-digit-of-20152015

Answer (score 3):

The leftmost digit of a positive integer $x$ is $d$ if the fractional part of $\log_{10}(x)$ is in the interval $[\log_{10}(d), \log_{10}(d+1))$.

Lin this case $\log_{10}(2016^{2016}) = 2016 \log_{10}(2016) \approx
6661.8529$.  The fractional part $0.8529\ldots$ is between
$\log_{10}(7) \approx .8451$ and $\log_{10}(8) \approx 0.9031$, 
so the first digit is indeed $7$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But what if you have't got a calculator or a logarithmic table?

Comment: In principle you can approximate the log by hand, but it would be pretty ugly.  So go get a calculator!

Comment: Yeah that's really better.  Thank you very much.